# get the distinct elements of an ArrayType column in a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 3 columns named *id*, *feat1* and *feat2*. *feat1* and *feat2* are in the form of Array of String:

```
Id, feat1,feat2
------------------
1, ["feat1_1","feat1_2","feat1_3"],[] 

2, ["feat1_2"],["feat2_1","feat2_2"]

3,["feat1_4"],["feat2_3"]
```

I want to get the list of distinct elements inside each feature column, so the output will be:

```
distinct_feat1,distinct_feat2
-----------------------------  
["feat1_1","feat1_2","feat1_3","feat1_4"],["feat2_1","feat2_2","feat2_3]
```

what is the best way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `collect_set` to find the distinct values of the corresponding column after applying the `explode` function on each column to unnest the array element in each cell. Suppose your data frame is called `df`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val distinct_df = df.withColumn("feat1", explode(col("feat1"))).
                     withColumn("feat2", explode(col("feat2"))).
                     agg(collect_set("feat1").alias("distinct_feat1"), 
                         collect_set("feat2").alias("distinct_feat2"))

distinct_df.show
+--------------------+--------------------+
|      distinct_feat1|      distinct_feat2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[feat1_1, feat1_2...|[, feat2_1, feat2...|
+--------------------+--------------------+


distinct_df.take(1)
res23: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([WrappedArray(feat1_1, feat1_2, feat1_3, feat1_4),
                                                WrappedArray(, feat2_1, feat2_2, feat2_3)])
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom for your response. It does work as you illustrated. In case the number of feature columns is not known in advance, can you think of a solution that doesn't require hardcoding?

Comment: How would you do this with SparkR?

Comment: @MasoudTavazoei A little late, but you see my answer for a version that works with non-hardcoded values.

Answer (score 2):

one more solution for spark 2.4+

```
.withColumn("distinct", array_distinct(concat($"array_col1", $"array_col2")))
```

beware, if one of columns is null, result will be null

Answer (score 0):

The method provided by Psidom works great, here is a function that does the same given a Dataframe and a list of fields:

```
def array_unique_values(df, fields):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_set, explode
    from functools import reduce
    data = reduce(lambda d, f: d.withColumn(f, explode(col(f))), fields, df)
    return data.agg(*[collect_set(f).alias(f + '_distinct') for f in fields])
```

And then:

```
data = array_unique_values(df, my_fields)
data.take(1)
```