# Get distinct elements from rows of type ArrayType in Spark dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
    root
     |-- e: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

For example, initiate a dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(Seq("73","73"), null, null, null, Seq("51"), null, null, null, Seq("52", "53", "53", "73", "84"), Seq("73", "72", "51", "73")).toDF("e")

df.show()

+--------------------+
|                   e|
+--------------------+
|            [73, 73]|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                [51]|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|[52, 53, 53, 73, 84]|
|    [73, 72, 51, 73]|
+--------------------+
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
+--------------------+
|                   e|
+--------------------+
|                [73]|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|                [51]|
|                null|
|                null|
|                null|
|    [52, 53, 73, 84]|
|        [73, 72, 51]|
+--------------------+
```

I am trying the following udf:

```
def distinct(arr: TraversableOnce[String])=arr.toList.distinct
val distinctUDF=udf(distinct(_:Traversable[String]))
```

But it only works when the rows aren't null i.e.

```
df.filter($"e".isNotNull).select(distinctUDF($"e"))
```

gives me

```
+----------------+
|          UDF(e)|
+----------------+
|            [73]|
|            [51]|
|[52, 53, 73, 84]|
|    [73, 72, 51]|
+----------------+
```

but

```
df.select(distinctUDF($"e"))
```

fails. How do I make the udf handle null in this case? Alternatively, if there's a simpler way of getting the unique values, I'd like to try that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801889/get-the-distinct-elements-of-an-arraytype-column-in-a-spark-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `when().otherwise()` to apply your UDF only when the column value is not `null`.  In this case, `.otherwise(null)` can also be skipped, as it defaults to `null` when not specifying the `otherwise` clause.

```
val distinctUDF = udf( (s: Seq[String]) => s.distinct )

df.select(when($"e".isNotNull, distinctUDF($"e")).as("e"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two months after you've asked the question, with the release of Spark 2.4.0, the function [`array_distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#array_distinct(Column):Column) was introduced, which does exactly as intended.